# why eval('{a:23}') gives me 23 instead of {a:23}?

Tags: javascript

I have this bit of javascript code in the browser

```
console.log( eval('{a:23}'));
```

and it prints 
23

I was expecting instead to see

```
[Object]
```

can somebody explain ?

thanks

Comment: The curly braces are parsed as block statement delimiters, and the `a` is parsed as a label. Try `({a:23})`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In that context, `{` starts a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), not an object literal.

`a:` is then a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

That leaves `23`.